# Проблема с виртуальной машиной при созданий клон-сайта

Tags: kali-linux, виртуальная-машина, взлом

При созданий клон-сайта в Kali linux, с помощью setoolkit в виртуальны машина oracle,vmware. Ошибка Something went wrong, printing the error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webattack/tabnabbing/source.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]